# Interface Builder: custom fonts don't appear in list

Tags: xcode6, interface-builder, uifont

I've added some custom fonts to the project:

[image]

The fonts are added to the target, are included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" list, and are also added to Info.plist under Fonts Provided by Application.

However, those fonts don't show correctly in the Interface Builder. It shows the font family (CentraleSans), but gives me only 2 font choices for that family.

[image]

Moreover, the actual font IB ends up using seems random (the final selection can be CentraleSansBold or CentraleSansBook, or other ones, for the same family/font values I pick). Notice how in the screenshot above it says "CentraleSansBook", even though that was not an option in the drop down list. Is this an IB bug?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found a way to make it work. I had to install the custom fonts on my Mac. Double-click on the font file in Finder, then click "Install Font". After that the font will appear in the drop down list in IB.